# Android why am I having double ripple effect on background selector?

Tags: android, android-listview, material-design, android-selector, rippledrawable

I am having a double ripple effect on press item(a ripple effect from center of the item and a second from the point touched), here is a screenshot of my problem:

[image]

But this only happen on the first item, in the others the ripple effect works well. I am following this [udacity project](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine-Version-2) and I did realize that they have the same problem.

Here are my resources I am using:

drawable-v21/touch_selector.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_pressed="true">
      <ripple android:color="@color/grey" />
  </item>

  <item android:drawable="@color/light_blue" android:state_activated="true" />

  <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

row_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/touch_selector"
  android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
  ...
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_main.xml

```
...
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"
    tools:listitem="@layout/row_item" />
...
```

How can I fix this double ripple effect on item pressed? (Again, this just happen in the first item, the others work well).

**Here is the source code:** https://github.com/epool/SpotifyStreamer/tree/stage-2

Comment: The bug has to be somewhere else in your code.  Plus, more detail is needed.  For example, is it the first item in the list, or the first one pressed.  Are you registering two fragments or Recyclerviews that overlap?

Comment: @easycheese yes, it is the first item in the list, not the first pressed. The activity has two fragments, the left side fragment is where the list is, and right fragment is another list with the same issue. I'm not in my laptop right now, but I could add more code later if it is necessary, the code is very similar to the udacity github link.

Comment: Here is the source code: https://github.com/epool/SpotifyStreamer/tree/stage-2

Answer (score 1):

I had also the same problem, and after hunting for it for hours, I realized that the ripple effect is triggered twice because I put `v.setEnabled(false)` then `v.setEnabled(true)` inside the `onClickListener` to disable the view while the onClick is ongoing.

Removing them solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

@epool,

I downloaded your project and ran it. 
The problem occurred not only on the first item of the list, but on others as well. I did notice that it was inconsistent though, it didn't happen every single time.

It seems like you might have set the ripple effect, or at least enabled it, on a different place as well.

If you simply delete the line of code below, it should work just fine! =]

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
   <ripple android:color="@color/grey" />
</item>
```

Just on a side note, I clicked multiple times on different items of the list to see how they would behave, and by doing that, I got the following error:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: src.length=2048 srcPos=2048 dst.length=2048 dstPos=0 length=2047

That's on your **Binder.java** file, on line **446**. So you might want to address that.

If you have any other question, please let me know.

Comment: I have deleted the ripple item, that works, but the current item selected(the blue) is no longer having the ripple effect when is pressed.

Comment: Weird. When I run your project, I don't see anything blue...
I changed "android:state_activated" to "android:state_selected" to test, and I did see a blue item after I searched for an artist. Even on that item, it worked for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what device you are using, but in theory the row should be blue on tablets with sw-600dp.

Comment: Let me test on different devices. I will get back to you in a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the double ripple can be avoided if instead of setting the `background` on the list item, it is set as the `listSelector` on the list view itself, or not including the `state_pressed` in the item's background selector.